# OfficeJS (Excel): not showing NamedItem that exists in sheet

Tags: office-js

I have a sheet in which I have defined a named range ("my_range").  I would like to enumerate the named ranges in a given Worksheet, and I have the following code:

```
async function run() {
    await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
        const sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1")
        sheet.load([ "name", "names" ])
        await ctx.sync()
        console.log(sheet.toJSON())
    });
}
```

Surprisingly, this prints something like:

```
{"id": "...", "name": "Sheet1", "names": []}
```

I would have expected at least one item in the array, representing my named range.  Does anybody have an idea of why this does not seem to be working?

On an unrelated note, is there an OfficeJS Slack/Discourse group for discussion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worksheet.names API only returns the named range under worksheet scope.

To create a named range under worksheet scope, please create it with `Sheet1!my_range` instead of `my_range`.

If you go to "Name Manager" under Formulas ribbon, you'll see a dialog like below screenshot, and you can check the scope of named ranges there.

[image: Name Manager]

======================================================================

It seems you can't view the scope on Excel for Mac. So I created a very simple gist to help Mac users. Below is the screenshot.

[image: Script Lab Gist]

To use it, please install "Script Lab" from Office Add-in store, and [import](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import) this [gist](https://gist.github.com/3bfa781af9f9c1172bf3ab5cd1866f2d).

Comment: Excellent, that does the trick.  However, under Excel for Mac, is there a way to view the scope for a defined name?

Comment: It seems Excel for Mac lack of this functionality. But with Office Add-in's help, you can extend Excel by yourself :) I created a simple gist and please check my edited answer.

Comment: Ha, nice!  Your UI looks better than Native Excel